# modify attribute via list comprehension

Tags: python

If I have a simple class

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop=False
```

why does this not work

```
l=[a,b,c]
[c.prop=True for c in l]

for c in l:
    print c.prop
```

It shows invalid symtax. but the regular loop works

```
for c in l:
     c.prop=True
```

Any idea why list comprehension fails here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List comprehensions in Python are made for building lists. The comprehension loops through an iterable and evaluates an expression - it appends the result of the expression to the list it is building.

This would clearly not work with statements - what do they evaluate to? What value would they return? Python cannot build a list because of this, and it is a `SyntaxError`. This applies to things like the ternary operator as well.

When you don't need to build a list, or when you want to perform an operation iterating through a list, use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 4):

That's because list comprehensions are not meant for mutations, it's not considered Pythonic, if you want to mutate something in a list comprehension, use a `for` loop instead

Comment: thanks. LC seemed to be the way to have one-line loops. did not know that there ere reason to limit them in their fucntionality

Comment: There is a reason, that reson is not called "pythonic", but "functional programming", specifically: "referential transparency".

Comment: @user1734278 Python promotes a certain style of coding, if you want no limits go to Perl, but it's not very pretty there imo